# How to write a shell script to append multiple line of data to 3-different file at a time and search if that data already exists and ignore it?

Tags: linux, shell

Tried using:
sed -i $ a 'hello' << foo.txt

when I'm trying to use is for multiple files I unattended. Someone plz help to sort this out. Appreciate your response! Thanks

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: "Append multiple line of data" from where is this data coming? "and search if that data already exists and ignore it" You want to 1 append, and then 2.... not append if it's already in there? Please edit the question to share more about what you are trying to do and explain better what you intend to happen. I still feel that `tee` is the proper answer here after a grep is performed to fulfill the second (which should be first) requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the `tee` command. Something like

```
echo "new line" | tee -a file1 file2 file3
```

To keep it from sending also to stdout you can redirect afterwards to `/dev/null`

```
echo "new line" | tee -a file1 file2 file3 > /dev/null
```

You can read more at its manpage `man tee`.

Comment: That looks good but what I'm trying to do is add multiple values continuously to all the 3 files. let's say it like when we run a script we will be asked to input value I need it that way.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me, nor does your edited question. I feel like perhaps you have a misunderstanding about how shell works. This answer fit your question before you edited and moved the goal post.